# DCMTK library compilation for android

Tags: android, cross-compiling, cmake-gui, dcmtk

I am trying to compile DCMTK source code to generate library for android platform. I used CMAKE3.12.1 to compile the source code. After setting SDK  and NDK I am getting this error :

> CMake Error at CMake/dcmtkUseAndroidSDK.cmake:301 (MESSAGE):   Please
>   select which Android emulator Android Virtual Device (AVD)
>   configuration to use! Call Stack (most recent call first):
>   CMake/dcmtkPrepare.cmake:179 (DCMTK_ANDROID_START_EMULATOR)
>   CMakeLists.txt:17 (INCLUDE)*

I have generated AVD using Android Studio still I am not getting option to select AVD in ANDROID_EMULATOR_AVD drop down in CMAKE GUI. I have added image of CMAKE-GUI. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uiqls.png)
Please help me to solve this issue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this problem!!!
Just added JAVA_HOME in my PATH to solve this..
If JAVA_HOME is not set this problem will occur.